# TypeORM createQueryBuilder: Is possible to use table name as string instead of entity

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

In my current scenario, a third party will be creating tables dynamically on my DB, and storing the table name as a `varchar` and column names as `jsonb` in other table which is defined as an Entity in my NestJS backend.

This is so I can keep track (and query) these tables, since I have no control over its creation.

For this purpose I'd like to use **TypeORM**'s `createQueryBuilder` instead of using raw queries as its easier for me to play with abstraction.

As far as I know TypeORMs `createQueryBuilder` needs a defined Entity in the `from` clause.

Something like this:

```
return await getManager()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select('*')
  .from(MyDefinedModel, 'modelAlias')
  .getRawMany();
}
```

So I'd like to do something like:

```
const tableName = await getDynamicallyGenetaredTableNames().getFirstOne()
// now tableName points to a string that is a table name, i.e 'table-data-192239'

 return await getManager()
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select('*')
  .from(tableName, 'tableAlias')
  .getRawMany();
```

So passing the table name I point to the right table, but TypeORM (and TS) complains because that `tableName` is a string, and not an Entity (Class) type

I really don't want to type-cast and start doing nasty things if there is something cleaner to achieve this.
I didn't find any solution in the official docs

Any brilliant ideas out there?
Thanks, y'all

Comment: do you find solution ?

Comment: I just used raw queries for now, via 'repository.query('SQL QUERY HERE')'

Answer (score 2):

We can pass table name instead of Entity for `getRepository`.

```
let tableName = 'user';
let query = getRepository(tableName).createQueryBuilder(tableName);
```

Comment: Thanks! But can we pass a table name name that is not defined as an entity? That's the point

Answer (score 2):

You can select from a table by its table name without defining an entity before like this:

```
const res = await manager
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select()
  .from("tableName", null)
  .where("tableName.id = :id", { id: 1 })
  .getRawMany();
```

Be sure that you set the second parameter of the `from()` explicitly to null.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a raw query:

```
import { getManager } from 'typeorm'

const tableName = await getDynamicallyGenetaredTableNames().getFirstOne()

// Use the table name in a raw SQL query
const result = await getManager().query(`SELECT * FROM ${tableName}`)
```